# pushout of topological Hausdorff spaces is not Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory

$A$, $X$, $Y$ are topological Hausdorff spaces, $f:A\to X$, $g:A\to Y$ continuous maps. I search an example where the pushout $Z$ of the morphisms $f$ and $g$ is not Hausdorff.

I thought if I take $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the standard topology, $A=\mathbb{Q}$ endowed with the subspace-topology of $\mathbb{R}$ I have to choose $f$ and $g$ such that $Z=\frac{X\coprod Y}{f(a)\sim g(a)\; \forall a\in A}$ endowed with the quotient topology is homeomorphic to $\frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Q}}$. Or I tried to construct something with $X=Y=S^1$.. Is my first approach ok? I'm not sure how to choose the maps, one of them is the inclusion, and the other map I don't know. Or could you give me an example? (I'm interested in something with $X=Y=S^1$, but not important).

Comment: The pushout of morphisms in a category $C$ is **per definition** an object in $C$. This applies in particular to $C=\mathrm{Haus}$, the category of Hausdorff spaces. The pushout of maps of Hausdorff spaces *is* a Hausdorff space. What is really going on here is the observation that the forgetful functor $\mathrm{Haus} \to \mathrm{Top}$ (which should not be forgotten) does not create (or preserve) pushouts. One can show that this functor is fully faithful and has a left adjoint ("largest Hausdorff quotient"), and hence $\mathrm{Haus}$ is cocomplete.

Comment: The standard example is $\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R} \leftarrow \mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Isn't the standard example rather $\mathbb R \hookleftarrow \mathbb R^+ \hookrightarrow \mathbb R$ ? (I imagine you want to talk about the real line with double origine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a way to make your first idea work, though the pushout isn’t $\Bbb R/\Bbb Q$.

Let $f:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto x$ and $g:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto -x$. The resulting pushout is the quotient of $\{0,1\}\times\Bbb R$ by the relation $\langle i,x\rangle\sim\langle j,y\rangle$ iff $\langle i,x\rangle=\langle j,y\rangle$, or $i\ne j$ and $x=-y\in\Bbb Q$. This space is not Hausdorff: if $\langle q_n:n\in\Bbb Q\rangle$ is a sequence of rationals converging to the irrational $\alpha$ in $\Bbb R$, then

$$\Big\langle[\langle 0,q_n\rangle]:n\in\Bbb N\Big\rangle$$

converges to both $[\langle 0,\alpha\rangle]$ and $[\langle 1,-\alpha\rangle]$ in this space.

Other more familiar examples are the [line with two origins and the branching line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold#Line_with_two_origins).

Comment: hi. thank you. what is i and j? is $i,j\in\{0,1\}$ and i=0 if $x\in X$, $i=1$ if $x\in Y$? And what does $<i,x>=<j,y>$ mean? I'm not sure if i understand this correctly. I interpret $<i,x>=<j,y>$: i=j and x=y, but i'm not sure.

Comment: @bunny: $\langle i,x\rangle$ is simply an ordered pair in $\{0,1\}\times\Bbb R$, so $i$ is $0$ or $1$, and $x$ is some real number. Yes, you can think of $\{0\}\times\Bbb R$ as $X$ and $\{1\}\times\Bbb R$ as $Y$.

Comment: ah ok, thank you. But the resuting quotient is not $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ as you said. I often have problems to understand such quotients. I glue the  X to Y or i glue the rationals of X to the negative of x, a rational number contained in Y or how to understand this? Another thing ist: If I want to "create" such a pushout of topological space, I would not know how to choose the maps to get a "suitable quotient" but I think this problem is because I have problems to understand such quotiens.

Comment: @bunny: You glue the rational $q$ in $X$ to the rational $-q$ in $Y$. This means, for instance, that the sequence $\langle 1,1.4,1.41,1.414,\ldots\rangle$ in $X$ converging to $\sqrt2$ is glued to the sequence $\langle -1,-1.4,-1.41,-1.414,\ldots\rangle$ in $Y$ converging to $-\sqrt2$. These become the same sequence in the quotient, but the points $\sqrt2$ in $X$ and $-\sqrt2$ in $Y$ are still distinct in the quotient, so the sequence converges to both of them.

Comment: ah ok, but in the case <i,x>=<j,y>, i glue X to Y? This would give us a different result, or how to understand this? I'm embarrassed..^^. But it is the first time that I asked questions something like that because it is anonymous. And now I learn something for the future, it helps a lot. Thanks:).

Comment: @bunny: The statement that $\langle i,x\rangle\sim\langle j,y\rangle$ whenever $\langle i,x\rangle=\langle j,y\rangle$ just says that every point is related to itself; every point gets glued to itself, but of course that doesn’t actually do anything. This is done in order to make $\sim$ a genuine equivalence relation on $X\sqcup Y$, so that the quotient is $(X\sqcup Y)/\sim$. The only gluing that actually matters is the described by the second part of the definition of $\sim$, the part that glues together the two copies of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: aaah okay! I understand! This was really helpful, thank you very much!!

Comment: @bunny: You’re very welcome!

Comment: Doesn't the sequence converge to $(0,\alpha)$ and $(1,-\alpha)$ ?

Comment: @Stefan: It does indeed; that’s a nasty typo. (At least I got it right in the example in my comment to bunny.) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

These separation properties often fail to be preserved when something is not closed. When $X=Y=S^1$, you can take $A$ to be the open arc $A=\{(a_1,a_2)\in S^1\mid a_2>0\}$, the map $f:A\to X$ is the inclusion, and $g:A\to Y$ is the inclusion as well. So we basically just glue the two copies of $S^1$ along the arc $A$. The constructed space is not Hausdorff.

Comment: great, thank you, I understand!!